# Is there a limitation with how Spring JPA deals with multi level inheritance when using a JOINED inheritance strategy?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, inheritance

I am working with a Spring Boot application using a PostgreSQL database. I am running into issues when using JPA 2.1 with multi level inheritance.

I am trying to understand if am trying to do something that is not supported, or if I am doing something wrong.

To illustrate, I put together a basic three level inheritance structure as follows using a JOINED inheritance strategy:

**Class A**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="dtype")
public class ClassA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**Class B**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    private String fieldInB;

    public String getFieldInB() {
        return fieldInB;
    }

    public void setFieldInB(String fieldInB) {
        this.fieldInB = fieldInB;
    }
}
```

**Class C**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class ClassC extends ClassB {

    private String fieldInC;

    public String getFieldInC() {
        return fieldInC;
    }

    public void setFieldInC(String fieldInC) {
        this.fieldInC = fieldInC;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[id: " + getId() + "; fieldInB: " + getFieldInB() + "; fieldInC: " + getFieldInC() + "]";
    }
}
```

The repositories are all straightforward:

**Repositories**

```
public interface ClassARepository extends CrudRepository<ClassA, Long> { }

public interface ClassBRepository extends CrudRepository<ClassB, Long> { }

public interface ClassCRepository extends CrudRepository<ClassC, Long> { }
```

I then wrote the following simple section of code to check that it is working:

**Code to Test**

```
    log.info("Checking inheritance structure ...");

    // Create object
    ClassC classC = new ClassC();
    classC.setFieldInB("bbbbb");
    classC.setFieldInC("ccccc");
    classCRepository.save(classC);
    log.info("--- Saved instance of class C.");

    // Test repository for Class C
    long countC = classCRepository.count();
    log.info("--- Result of classCRepository.count(): " + countC);
    for (ClassC  c : classCRepository.findAll()) {
        log.info("--- Item returned from classCRepository.findAll(): " + c.toString());
    }

    // Test repository for Class A
    long countA = classARepository.count();
    log.info("--- Result of classARepository.count(): " + countA);
    for (ClassA  a : classARepository.findAll()) {
        log.info("--- Item returned from classARepository.findAll(): " + a.toString());
    }

    // Test repository for Class B
    long countB = classBRepository.count();
    log.info("--- Result of classBRepository.count(): " + countB);
    for (ClassB  b : classBRepository.findAll()) {
        log.info("--- Item returned from classBRepository.findAll(): " + b.toString());
    }

    log.info("Inheritance structure check complete.");
```

The output I get from the above code is as follows:

**Output**

```
Checking inheritance structure ...
--- Saved instance of class C.
--- Result of classCRepository.count(): 1
--- Item returned from classCRepository.findAll(): [id: 10; fieldInB: bbbbb; fieldInC: ccccc]
--- Result of classARepository.count(): 1
--- Item returned from classARepository.findAll(): [id: 10; fieldInB: bbbbb; fieldInC: ccccc]
--- Result of classBRepository.count(): 1
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
ERROR: column classb0_.dtype does not exist
```

As you can see from the output, I can successfully retrieve my object from either the repository for the root class (ClassA) or the repository at the other end of the inheritance structure (ClassC), but when I try to use the repository for the middle class (ClassB), an exception gets thrown.

It seems that some component is expecting the database table for ClassB to have the discriminator column, when only the table for ClassA should require it. (And for the sake of completeness, adding the @DiscriminatorColumn annotation to ClassB does nothing.)

The actual exception stack-trace (cut down for the sake of brevity) is as follows:

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:242) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column classb0_.dtype does not exist
  Position: 106
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:645) ~[postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar:9.4]
    ...
```

What is a little puzzling about all of this is that, if I change nothing but the inheritance strategy, and run the same code with either the SINGLE_TABLE or TABLE_PER_CLASS, the code runs perfectly.

I have spent considerable time going through all manner of documentation on this (from Spring to PostgreSQL to the JPA 2.1 Spec), but have so far had no luck.

**Questions**

In summary, I'd like to know:

1. Is this normal documented behaviour for JPA 2.1 (and if so, please point me to the where it is documented)?
2. Is this normal, but undocumented, behaviour for JPA 2.1?
3. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?
4. Is there something wrong with the Spring JPA implementation?
5. Is there an alternative workaround that allows me to still use multi level inheritance with a JOINED strategy?

(Note that I have considered @MappedSuperclass but it is not suitable for my needs.)

Comment: first let me claim: "It should work": the error is: "ERROR: column classb0_.dtype does not exist" -- have you checked that your database tables and columns are correct?

Comment: Also, JPA is just a specification. Which implementation are you using? Hibernate? EclipseLink? Something else? Did you generate the schema or did you let the engine generate it for you?

Comment: @JB Nizet: according to the stacktrace `HibernateJpaDialect` its Hibernate.

Comment: @Ralph now I feel stupid. I managed to miss the stack trace somehow.

Comment: @Ralph: Yes, I checked the database columns, they are all correct.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I let the engine generate the schema for me.